# Connecting phone to external display and launching app

Tags: android

Is it possible to create an app which launches on an external display when HDMI is connected to the phone?

Basically. I want to create an app that works like a mini OS, similar to Samsung Dex.

To start off, I'd just like to have the app launch automatically when HDMI is connected and adjust to the screen size, then show the user home screen app icons etc.

Is this possible?

I found some apps on the app store that do this:

[Sentio desktop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sentio.desktop)

[Leena](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.m_lang.leena)

How are they doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an open source project that can help you. [right here](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy)